# Get all years between two dates in Laravel/Lumen Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, lumen

i'm making an API in Lumen for a car insurance company, in their **mysql** database table they have two dates (a starting date and an ending date) for each vehicle.

I need to create a method to return a JSON response with all of the possible years in **between** the starting date and ending date. 
*For example, if start_date is 1992-02-10 and end_date is 1994-02-24, then i need to return* `[1992, 1993, 1994]` *and so on.*

I was wondering if there's any way to do this via Eloquent/SQL or if i'm gonna have to load all of the dates and filter them in PHP.

If so, then how do should i join both column's rows into one result set with unique years in Eloquent? Again, if possible i'd like to just retrieve the years from the DB and not the entire date.

```
SELECT YEAR(start_date) from logodb.vehicles
UNION 
SELECT YEAR(end_date) from logodb.vehicles
```

In vanilla MySQL i could get the unique dates like that, but how do i do that in Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DB::raw` in place of Laravel/Eloquent model magic in almost any instance.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries

```
User::addSelect(DB::raw("YEAR(start_date) AS `start_year`"))
    ->addSelect(DB::raw("YEAR(end_date) AS `end_year`"))
    ->get();
```

This, for instance, would return a model object with `$user->start_year` equaling the result of `YEAR(start_date)`.

I'm not sure what the purpose of your `UNION` is. MySQL's documentation says it joins SELECT statements, but you should be able to do `YEAR(end_date) AS end_year` just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. My TL told me specifically not to use DB::raw() however, so that was not an option unfortunately. I managed to get all of the dates like this:

```
$startDates = $this->model->select('start_date');
$dates  = $this->model->select('end_date')->union($startDates)->orderBy('end_dates')->get();
```

Union will automatically return only distinct rows so i got the list of dates i needed, and with Carbon i easily extracted the years as such:

```
$date->end_date->year
```